# Como trocar a mascara de um input tipo data

Tags: javascript, input, data

Como resolvo este problema ?

quero remover este "dd/mm/aaaa"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: Quero remover este "dd/mm/aaaa"]

Comment: Você quer só remover o conteúdo e deixar vazio ou deseja mostrar algo?

Comment: cade o codigo ?

Comment: So deixar vazio

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode "esconder" a máscara definindo a cor do texto default como transparente, e depois colocando na cor preto de volta quando o `input` estiver focado ou for válido. Funcionou no Chrome e no FireFox, o IE parece que não aceita o `type=date`, mas de qq forma também fica vazio e quando clica no `input` ou escreve algo o texto fica preto.

```css
input[type=date]::-webkit-datetime-edit{ color: transparent; }
input[type=date]:valid::-webkit-datetime-edit{ color: #000; }
input[type=date]:focus::-webkit-datetime-edit{ color: #000; }

input[type=date]{ color: transparent; }
input[type=date]:valid{ color: #000; }
input[type=date]:focus{ color: #000; }
```

```html
<input type="date" required>
```