# Efeito no input type="date"

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa noite, galera!

Estou com uma pequena dificuldade em fazer um efeito no `input type="date"`. Consigo fazer normalmente no `input type="text"` (primeira print mostra sem o efeito e o segundo mostra com o efeito), mas no `date` ele fica aparecendo o `"dd/mm/aaaa"` abaixo do texto (como mostra o terceiro print e o quarto com o efeito). Existe alguma forma de fazer isso sumir e quando clicasse no input ele aparecesse?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código

```
Style:

.effect{
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.effect ~ .focus-border{
    position: absolute; 
    margin-left: 44px; 
    bottom: 0; left: 50%; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    transition: 0.4s;
    z-index: 2;}

.effect:focus ~ .focus-border,

.has-content.effect ~ .focus-border{
    width: 80%; transition: 0.4s; left: 0;
}

.effect ~ h3{
    position: absolute; margin-left: 44px; width: 100%; top: 8px; color: #aaa; transition: 0.3s; letter-spacing: 0.5px; cursor: default;
}

.effect:focus ~ h3, .has-content.effect ~ h3{
    top: -16px; font-size: 12px; color: #4CAF50; transition: 0.3s;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="col-3 input-effect-data">

       <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt" id="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <input type="date" class="effect" required>
       <h3>Insira sua data de nascimento</h3>
       <span class="focus-border"></span>

    </div>
```

Comment: posta o código de como está fazendo, que ajuda a visualização do problema

Comment: Coloquei o código, mas não consegui formatar direito, sou novo por aqui. Espero que dê para entender

Comment: Isso deve te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298114/como-trocar-a-mascara-de-um-input-tipo-data/298132#298132

Comment: Resolvido! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode determinar que quando ele for inválido, atribui uma cor transparente no `dd/mm/aaaa` e quando ele for selecionado, atribui uma cor preta ao `dd/mm/aaaa`:

```css
.effect:required:invalid::-webkit-datetime-edit{
 color: transparent;
}
.effect:focus::-webkit-datetime-edit{
 color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="date" name="data" required="required" class="effect">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, estava quebrando a cabeça pra resolver isso! Muito obrigado!